# Классифицировать на основе нескольких входных изображений, а не по одному изображению

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, классификация

Необходима такая нейросеть, которая на основе произвольного количества фото выдает прогноз. То есть например по пяти определенным фото прогноз 1, по восьми другим фото прогноз 2. Все аналогично обычному использованию нейронных с той лишь разницей, что вместо одного обучающего фото и одного фото, по которому делается прогноз, используется произвольное количество фото от 1 до 20.
Если обучать нейросеть на одном изображении, то качество полученной модели будет значительно ниже.
Рекуррентные нейронные сети (RNN) должны подойти под эту задачу, но мне не удалось найти пример хорошего кода/статьи, где были бы использованы RNN для классификации изображений. Хотелось бы найти именно примеры на ЯП python в keras, tensorflow.

Comment: Ну вам всё-таки надо как-то скрестить CNN и RNN. Чтобы картинки "распознавала" CNN, а результаты работы CNN на нескольких картинках дальше обрабатывала RNN. Я не настолько силён в нейросетях, чтобы пойти дальше теоретизирования на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

Да как же "не удалось найти пример":

> https://medium.com/@nathaliejeans/how-i-classified-images-with-recurrent-neural-networks-28eb4b57fc79
> https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.ipynb
> https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples
> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129411/how-can-recurrent-neural-networks-be-used-for-sequence-classification

Ну и [Sequential Image Classification](https://paperswithcode.com/task/sequential-image-classification)

или

[RNN for sequence classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129411/how-can-recurrent-neural-networks-be-used-for-sequence-classification)